# database not taking the table

Tags: php, mysql

i am relatively new in phpmysql.i need some help...

i am using wamp server in windows7.server version is 2.2.22 and php version is 5.3.13.Name of my database is `db_attendance1`. I have two table namely `users` and `leave`.In users table i have following column

```
empID(int)
username(varchar)
password(varchar)
mac(varchar)
ip(varchar)
```

and in leave table i have following column

```
lid(int)
empname(varchar)
username(varchar)
nod(int)
sdate(date)
edate(date)
reason(varchar)
action(varchar)
```

Now i want to use empID in leave table.how can i use it.i have to say that i already apply a code but its not working.Its giving the following error..

## 1005 - Can't create table 'db_attendance1.leave' (errno: 150) (Details...)

and in details its showing the following..

InnoDB Documentation

Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys

[ Variables | Buffer Pool | InnoDB Status ]

and the code

```
create table `leave`(
lid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
empID INT,
empname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
nod INT NOT NULL,
sdate DATE,
edate DATE,
reason VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(lid),
FOREIGN KEY(empID) REFERENCES users(empID)
);
```

so whats wrong...please help me..

Comment: users > empID   is PRIMARY KEY ?

Comment: The type of the field in a foreign key must be the same as the type of the column they're referencing. Make sure that the properties of the two fields you are trying to link with a constraint are exactly the same.

Often, the 'unsigned' property on an ID column will catch you out.

Comment: yes empID is the primary key of users..

Answer (score 0):

```
create table users(

empID INT,
PRIMARY KEY(empID) /*<<< ADD THIS */
);
create table `leave`(
lid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
empID INT,
empname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
username VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
nod INT NOT NULL,
sdate DATE,
edate DATE,
reason VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(lid),
FOREIGN KEY(empID) REFERENCES users(empID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `INDEX(empID)` before your foreign key statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this to fix your error :

```
create table `leave`(
`lid` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`empID` INT(11),
`empname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`username` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`nod` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`sdate` DATE,
`edate` DATE,
`reason` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`lid`),
FOREIGN KEY(`empID`) REFERENCES users(`empID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=311 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`errno: 150` is a foreign key constraint error. You can get more details by immediately issuing the query `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` on the same connection after your failed `CREATE TABLE`.

Things to watch out for:

1. Does the parent table and attribute exist? (users.empid must exist FIRST)
2. Do the parent and child attributes have the same exact datatype? (signed INT in this case)
3. Is there an index (normal, unique, or primary key) on the attribute in both the parent and child tables?