# A foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql

I am relatively new in php and mysql.The problem that i am facing while i inserting value in my `leave` table.My `leave` table containing following  column..

1.lid(INT primary key)

2.empname(varchar)

3.username(varchar)

4.nod(INT)

5.sdate(DATE)

6.edate(DATE)

7.reason(varchar)

8.action(varchar)

9.empID (INT FOREIGN KEY)

here `empID` is the `foreign key` references from `users` table. The problem that im facing while inserting values into the `leave` table.ERROR is given below

**Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_attendance1`.`leave`, CONSTRAINT `leave_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`empID`) REFERENCES `users` (`empID`))**

here i just send  the query and here it is..

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `leave` 
           (`empname`, `username`,
            `nod`, `sdate`, `edate`,
            `reason`,`action`) 
            VALUES ('$empname', '$username', 
            '$nod', '$sdate', 
            '$edate', '$reason','');",
            $dbCon) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: sure about empID into users table first...

Comment: Dear friend why you post duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139572/database-not-taking-the-table/16139718#16139718

Answer (score 9):

You can put

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

and run your query. Once you are done again set it back to 1 by

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: This might work but could also result in some invalid data making it into your tables. Only turn off foreign keys when you're sure that the error is spurious.

Answer (score 8):

A foreign key constraint means that you one table doesn't accept inserts, updates or deletes that would 'break' the foreign key. This means, you can't update a EmpID if the new EmpID doesn't exist in the users. You can't add a new EmpID if it doesn't exist in the users table, etcetera.
So to solve this issue, you need to make sure that the EmpID you're trying to add to table 'leave', first exists in table 'users'.
Foreign keys can be a real powerful item, but can be a real pain too. Since the DB you're working on had foreign key constraints, I suggest you read on them a bit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

Answer (score 0):

Borniet, you helped me solve my similar problem.

@OP - All I had to do to fix this was create a corresponding row in the table so that the foreign key would exist. 
E.g. Table 1 has column Name
Table 2 has column friends_name, a foreign key tied to Name in table 1.
I got this error because I was trying to insert a row into table 2, where the friends_name referenced a non existing Name in table 1. So I created the name and we're off to the races :).